# redirecting user based on IP address and timestamp values

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I need some more help with a script.  I have pieced together the following from several examples but I'm falling short when it comes to comparing the results and the IP address and timestamp.  As it stands, I'm trying to redirect a user to another page if they have accessed a certain area on my site for more then 10 minutes.

My MySQL table consists of the following columns:

ID, client_ip, submitted_time

Here's my current code:

```
 <?php
 $ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

 $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","visitors");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 $query = "SELECT count(`id`) AS 'count' FROM `visits` WHERE `client_ip` = '$ipaddress'
         AND 'submitted_time' = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
       LIMIT 1";
 $result = mysql_query($link, $query);

   if ($result['count'] > 0) {
   echo "You have accessed this site in the last 10 minutes -- you are blocked!";}
   else
   {
   echo "You have access";

   exit;
    }

     ?>
```

I should be getting the "You have accessed this site in the last 10 minutes echo.....  But I'm getting You have access everytime.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong based on my current code?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the insides of variables with `var_dump($var);` or `print_r($var, true);`

Comment: Okay, I finally got this.. Had to make the following changes to my query:

    $query = "SELECT count(`id`) AS 'count'
       FROM `visits`
       WHERE 
         `client_ip` = '$ipaddress'
         AND `submitted_time` < '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('- 10 minutes'))."'
       LIMIT 1";
     $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, $q

Answer (score 0):

if you are checking whether they have accessed within the last 10 minutes you could use between

$query = "SELECT count(`id`) AS 'count' FROM `visits` WHERE `client_ip` = '$ipaddress'
         AND 'submitted_time' BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

although epends on the specifics of how you're trying to do it

Answer (score 0):

Information about your schema & data type is  insufficient. assuming `submitted_time` is `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`,

you have two problem.

- submitted_time is a column, so remove single quote, or use backtick.
- use `<=` rather than `=`, user can revisit over 10+ minutes
- `LIMIT 1` is not required. COUNT(*) always return 1 record. but this is not problem..

below query would work well:

```
   SELECT count(`id`) AS 'count'
   FROM `visits`
   WHERE `client_ip` = '$ipaddress'
        AND `submitted_time` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```